# Are all (or most) of the clips in the DBZ opening theme song from the series episodes?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

**Link to the opening theme song:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4vjJrGeh1c

I can recognize a few clips as being part of the series (e.g. Nappa tearing through the planes).

But the rest I cannot recollect being anywhere in the episodes. Do they appear in any part of any episode? If yes, is there a list connecting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of those clips are from the movies.
10s-21s;30s-36s : [The Tree of Might](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_The_Tree_of_Might)
21s-30s;36s-38s;41s-45s : [The World's Strongest](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_The_World%27s_Strongest)
38s-41s : [Dead Zone](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Dead_Zone)

Comment: Well I watched all three. Didn't know some of the clips were sped up. And they've already done Goku vs lookalike Goku!!. Thanks.